# redirect input using open() and close()

Tags: c, linux, process, io, operating-system

I'm trying to understand how the I/O between processes mechanism works.
I have tried to run this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
char *const paramList[] = {"/bin/cat"};
close(0);
open("./my_file", O_RDONLY);
execv("/bin/cat",paramList);
...
```

but got nothing going on. (it compiles, though)

what did I do wrong and what does my code do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs for `execv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv):

> The array of pointers *must* be terminated by a `NULL` pointer.

Thus, add `NULL` to the end of `paramList`.

If you're still having trouble, make sure to check the return values from all syscalls, and see if any of your calls are failing.

Comment: thanks, now I see the file  (my_file) content. is it similar to the command: "cat my_file"?

Comment: The command you executed was just `cat`, which reads from `stdin`. But, you replaced `stdin` (fd 0) with your file. Thus, it ends up *behaving like* `cat my_file`.

Comment: This is like `cat < my_file`, `my_file` being redirected to the standard input.